# Using time.Time in mongodb record

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I'm inserting new item in collection. Using official mongo go driver for this (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver).

```
collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), map[string]interface{}{
    "string":   "test",
    "integer":  123,
    "float":    0.123,
    "array":    []string{"t", "e", "s", "t"},
    "objectid": objectid.New(),
    "time":     time.Now(),
})
```

But as a result I have a problem with couple of properties: time.Time and objectid.ObjectID.

- time.Time is going as Object that is empty
- objectid.ObjectID - as Binary

[image]

I understand that it's only in alpha state, but maybe someone knows. Am I just doing it wrong or it's not yet implemented in the way as it should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass a `map` as the document to [`Collection.InsertOne()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Collection.InsertOne), the [`mongo`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo) package will use the [`mongo.TransformDocument()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#TransformDocument) to convert it to a [`*bson.Document`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#Document) value, because most operations are only implemented on `bson.Document`s.

The current transformation implementation does not handle [`objectid.ObjectID`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/objectid#ObjectID) nor the [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) types. It could and probably should, and I assume it will, but currently it doesn't.

If you want these types to end up with proper types in MongoDB, you may construct and pass a `*bson.Document` yourself, in which you can explicitly dictate what the types of the properties should be.

This is an equivalent insert statement to yours, using [`bson.NewDocument()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#NewDocument) to create the document manually:

```
res, err := coll.InsertOne(context.Background(), bson.NewDocument(
    bson.EC.String("string", "test"),
    bson.EC.Int64("integer", 123),
    bson.EC.Double("float", 0.123),
    bson.EC.ArrayFromElements("array",
        bson.VC.String("t"), bson.VC.String("e"),
        bson.VC.String("s"), bson.VC.String("t")),
    bson.EC.ObjectID("objectid", objectid.New()),
    bson.EC.DateTime("time", time.Now().UnixNano()/1e6), // Must pass milliseconds
))
```

It's more verbose, but it's explicit in what we want the result document in MongoDB to be. The result document will look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac5f598ca151255c6fc0ffb"),
    "string" : "test",
    "integer" : NumberLong(123),
    "float" : 0.123,
    "array" : [
        "t",
        "e",
        "s",
        "t"
    ],
    "objectid" : ObjectId("5ac5f598ca151255c6fc0ffa"),
    "time" : ISODate("2018-04-05T10:08:24.148Z")
}
```

Once the driver improves, I assume your original version will work as expected and produce a document identical to this in structure.

Comment: Does `bson.EC.DateTime` still exist in the beta? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the time to either a string or a unix timestamp. 
`time.Now()` is a type time which is a struct.

```
a := time.Now()
fmt.Println(a.Unix()) // Goes into mongodb as a int64
fmt.Println(a.String()) // Goes inot mongodb as a string
```

`1522868253` // Unix

`2018-04-04 13:57:33.495965 -0500 CDT m=+0.000363419` // String

So you can do this

```
collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), map[string]interface{}{
    "string":   "test",
    "integer":  123,
    "float":    0.123,
    "array":    []string{"t", "e", "s", "t"},
    "objectid": objectid.New(),
    "time":     time.Now().String(),
})
```

Comment: will `doc.time` be of type Date in mongo then? Otherwise queries on date will fail.